# Copy template in a test file

Tags: django, bash

In Django, I'm trying to copy the content of a template in a test file with `python manage.py dumpdata --indent=2 configurations.template | >> test.txt` command, but it didn't work. Could anyone be able to tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loose the `|` which is a *command pipe* in `bash` and do just

```
python manage.py dumpdata --indent=2 configurations.template >> test.txt
```

By the way the above command *appends* the contents of your `python` output to the `test.txt` file. If your intention is to create a new file out of the command output just use the re-direction with a single `>` to overwrite the file (or) create a new one if it didn't exist before.

```
python manage.py dumpdata --indent=2 configurations.template > test.txt
```